# Two questions for photo tables - FK and profile photo Q

Tags: database-design

1) I have two tables: Photos table and EXIF table. EXIF table stores the exif data of a photo.

Photo table has: `Photo_id, exif_id.`
EXIF table has: `exif_id, photo_id.`

So in essence, exif_id in photo table can be FK to exif_id in EXIF table. But photo_id in exif table can be FK to photo_id in photo table. Do i need two FKs here or can one FK do?

2) All sample schemas I have seen have a photo table for alum photos. What about profile album and the live profile photo? IS that usually a separate table or just a flag in the album table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is a little vague, but based on the given info:

1) you only need exif_id if you can have multiple EXIF rows per Photo_id.  If not, just go with Photo_id

2) I'd just use a flag to tell the photo type.

Comment: for 1 you mean only 1 table? OR 2 tables (photo table and EXIF table) and have the PK in EXIF table as photo_id again? Only reasn i made it two tables is to 'normalize' the data as EXIF data is about 15-20 colunms long.

Comment: if there is only one EXIF row per Photos row then they could be one table.  If many Photos row will not have a EXIF row then it is good to split them into two tables.  If you will only have 0 or 1 EXIF row per Photos rows then you don't need the exif_id.  If you will have multiple EXIF rows per Photos row then you need exif_id.